# how to get buttons to have its own pop up

Tags: javascript, html

I have two buttons. When each is pressed, I want the user to be able to enter an answer to the same question. What I have now the button and pop up work correctly but when button1 is pressed and the user enters something when pressing button2 what was entered in button1 appears. Is there a way I can continuing using one pop up div or would I have to make one individually for each button.

here is what I currently have:

```
    <div class='firstRow'>
        <button class="button">animal1</button>
        <button class="button">animal2</button>
    </div>
    <div id="myPopup">
        <span id="myPopupClose">x</span>
        <h3>Enter any animal</h3>
        <textarea id="myPopupTextbox" placeholder="Write something..."></textarea>
    </div>
    <script>
        var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("firstRow")[0];;
        var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
        var close = document.getElementById("myPopupClose");
        btn.onclick = function () {
            popup.style.display = "block";
            $("body").css("opacity", "0.25");
        }
        close.onclick = function () {
            popup.style.display = "none";
        }

        window.onclick = function (event) {
            if (event.target == popup) {
                popup.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the popup's *textarea* value each time a button is clicked, ensuring that the content is reset for every new input.

**Demo:**

```html
<style>
    #myPopup {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='firstRow'>
    <button class="button">animal1</button>
    <button class="button">animal2</button>
</div>
<div id="myPopup">
    <span id="myPopupClose">x</span>
    <h3>Enter any animal</h3>
    <textarea id="myPopupTextbox" placeholder="Write something..."></textarea>
</div>
<script>
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    var close = document.getElementById("myPopupClose");
    var textbox = document.getElementById("myPopupTextbox");

    buttons.forEach(function (button) {
        button.onclick = function () {
            //clear the textarea content
            textbox.value = "";
            popup.style.display = "block";
            $("body").css("opacity", "0.25");
        };
    });

    close.onclick = function () {
        popup.style.display = "none";
        $("body").css("opacity", "1");
    };

    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target == popup) {
            popup.style.display = "none";
            $("body").css("opacity", "1");
        }
    };
</script>
```